# Running Office 2003-2016 on Windows Server 2016

Tags: remote-desktop, desktop, remote, hosts, session

We have a small server farm which uses Windows Server Remote Desktop Services with remote sessions hosts and not remote virtualization hosts.

With virtualization hosts you are able to install Office separately per VM.

We have a customer that needs Office 2003 on a session host, and was wondering if this is possible, and if so how?

Are you able to assign licenses per user?

Comment: This entirely depends on the type of license you have.  In most cases it’s per machine.

Comment: This is a question you should ask the people you buy licenses from or who provides your technical expertise.

Comment: @music2myear I understand that, but the whole point of this forum is to ask and answer questions in a community that knows about these types of things...so I don't understand really what you're asking from me while I am asking on this forum.

Comment: 1/2 Like it or not, Microsoft licensing, like that of many large organizations' products, is complicated, to the point of being possibly or apparently inconsistent. Effectively, this means that, while it shouldn't be this way, the right answer for you might not be quite the same as the right answer for someone else. For what it's worth, Microsoft does attempt to publish clear explanations of their licenses, and this documentation is as available to you as it is to any of us. Further, penalties for incorrect licensing are legal issues.

Comment: 2/2 For these reasons and more, questions about licensing cannot be answered here on SuperUser, or really on any of the StackExchange sites. The best thing to do is to look up the Microsoft licensing documentation and study it, and go to the people you purchase licenses from, and ask them.

Comment: Here's a (brief) discussion from out Meta site on this: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5908/what-is-the-place-to-ask-about-legal-issues-associated-with-using-software